# MapBox GL: Issue with "Map.Off"

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, eventhandler

Within my Javascript Mapbox GL application, I'm having difficulty getting Map.off to work and therfore difficulty turning off event handlers.

I have several instances of objects (circles) created on a map (provided via mapbox gl) Each has several event handlers assigned, similar to the example on:
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/drag-a-point/

The difference is I have multiple instances of the point. Each of them can be dragged around the screen and placed. Problem is, when the user needs to preform another function on the map they can't turn off all event handlers corresponding to said points.

Though map.off works within "onUp" it doesn't have any effect within the bottom "else" section.

Below is the problem snippet of my code. buttons lead to MoveTree and stillTree being called.

```
//---MOVE TREES CONTENT---//

//Move all Trees 
function moveTree(){
    var currName;
    for (var i = 1; i <= trees.length; i++){               
        currName = "circle" + i;
        selectCheck(currName, true);
    }   
}

//Turn off all tree interaction 
function stillTree(){
    for (var i = 1; i <= trees.length; i++){
            currName = "circle" + i;
            selectCheck(currName, false);
        }
}

//Perform or restrict tree moving functionality
function selectCheck(currName, move){    
    if (move == true){
        map.on('mouseenter', currName, onEnter) 
        function onEnter(){
            map.setPaintProperty(currName, 'circle-color', '#3bb2d0');
            canvas.style.cursor = 'move';
        }

        map.on('mouseleave', currName, onLeave)
        function onLeave(){
            map.setPaintProperty(currName, 'circle-color', 'black');
            canvas.style.cursor = '';
        };

        map.on('mousedown', currName, onDown)
        function onDown(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            canvas.style.cursor = 'grab';
            map.on('mousemove', onMove);
            map.once('mouseup', onUp);  
        }

        function onUp(){                          
            map.off('mousemove', onMove);
            map.off('touchmove', onMove);               
        }

        function onMove(){
            map.getSource(currName).setData(geojson);
        }            
    }
    else{
        alert(move);
        map.off('mousemove');
        map.off('mouseenter');
        map.off('mousemove');
        map.off('touchmove');         
    }
}
```

Comment: extending each of the four lines to act more specifically, e.g: map.off('mousemove', currName, onMove); doesnt work either.

Comment: You said "they can't turn off all event handlers corresponding to said points.". Just a shot in the dark, but wouldn't this line never turn off the last event since you have <=? "(var i = 1; i <= trees.length; i++)". Try doing I < trees.length.

Comment: Cheers, though this causes no issue as both "movetree" the method calling to apply each tree's handlers and "stillTree" the method to remove them, iterate the same number of times i <= trees.length.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#off, two parameters must be provided to `map.off()`:

- `type(string)`: The event type previously used to install the listener.
- `listener(Function)`: The function previously installed as a listener.

So, the "else" section it should be something like this:

```js
else {
  alert(move);
  map.off('mousemove', onMove);
  map.off('mouseenter', onEnter);
  map.off('touchmove', onMove);         
}
```

Comment: In case your are reusing some good old pieces of code and are still wondering why it not working this time, passing one parameter to unbind all the listeners from an event used to work but this feature was dropped in a breaking change at the [0.25.0 version](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0250-september-29-2016).